# Terraform module throws error about requiring a string

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-modules

I've been trying to split my terraform code from one large file into separate modules. I keep running into an issue where the following error appears when running Terraform Plan.

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on modules/nsg/main.tf line 11, in resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "InternalProdNSGPrivate":
  11:   resource_group_name = "${module.rg.main-rg-id}"

Inappropriate value for attribute "resource_group_name": string required.
```

I created an `outputs.tf` file which has the following:

```
output "main-rg-id" {
  value = "${azurerm_resource_group.InternalProd}"
}
```

The `main.tf` for this module has the following:

```
module "global_variables" {
  source = "../global_variables"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "InternalProd" {
  name     = "Internal"
  location = "${module.global_variables.location}"
}
```

In the main.tf file for the NSG i have the following configured:

```
module "rg" {
  source = "../rg"
}
module "global_variables" {
  source = "../global_variables"
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "InternalProdNSGPrivate" {
  name                = "Internal-NSG"
  location            = "${module.global_variables.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${module.rg.main-rg-id}"
....
}
```

Not sure where im going wrong here with the configuration. Tried looking at multiple different resources, blogs, etc. but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`azurerm_resource_group.InternalProd` is an object representing the whole of `resource "azurerm_resource_group" "InternalProd"`.

To produce just the id of that object, you can access attribute `id` like this:

```
output "main-rg-id" {
  value = azurerm_resource_group.InternalProd.id
}
```